# getting nil in results dictionary in didCompleteWithResults delegate Facebook sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am using FBSDKShareDialog to share content on Facebook with FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedWeb mode, but when i click on can cel button on the left top, it goes to - (void)sharer:(id)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results delegate, and in this delegate i have given 
 if ([results count]>0)
    success
 else
    fail

so even if it is successful it is showing fail message,

is there any other way to track cancel action.